# Export or Set ANT_OPTS

Tags: java, windows, debugging, ubuntu, ant

I tried to do this:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n
```

and tried to to add options to /home/user/.bashrc with restart:

```
ANT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n
```

but I din not saw a listener for this port with netstat -l after ant start.
I am on Windows 7 x64 and my ANT process is on Ubuntu 15.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have no idea, what you want to do, but to make your settings you should call (with export in the beginning and quotes around the value):

```
export set ANT_OPTS='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n'
```